# Calculating the harmonic mean of 2 double numbers in C using a function

Tags: c

Im trying to create a function that will calculate 2 input numbers.

When im typing for example `1.0` and `5.0` im getting `0.00` in the output..

You will probably find that the problem is something very obvious to you, but understand im a total newbie, and I just now getting to pointers.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMS 50
double harmonic_mean(double number1, double number2);

int main(void)

{
    double num1, num2;
    printf("please enter two numbers to get the harmonic mean:\n");
    while ((scanf("%lf%lf", &num1, &num2)) == 2)
    {
        printf("%.2lf", harmonic_mean(num1, num2));
    }
    return 0;
}

double harmonic_mean(double number1, double number2)

{
    double harmonic, totalHarmonic;
    int total;
    int x, y;
    double numbers[MAXNUMS];
    for (x = 1, y = 0; x <= number2; x++, y++)

    {
        total = x;
        numbers[y] = number1++;
    }

    for (x = 0; x <= total; x++)
    {
        harmonic += (1/numbers[x]);
    }

    totalHarmonic = total/harmonic;

    return totalHarmonic;
}
```

tnx

Comment: The way to approach this is to trace the activity of your program, and compare the values of variables to what you were expecting.  You can either use the program to step through line by line, or you can add lots of print statements.

Comment: Argument `number2` is a `double` and you are only using it in the loop condition `x <= number2`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks, i see the issue in that point. im trying to calculate the harmonic mean of two numbers @PascalCuoq

Comment: Do you understand what a harmonic mean of two numbers is? Your function calculates anything but. [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#section_2).

Comment: The harmonic mean of two numbers `number1` and `number2` is `2 * number1 * number2 / (number1 + number2)` according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean

Comment: Are you trying to calculate harmonic mean of just two numbers or of arbitrary array of numbers? The formula for harmonic mean of two numbers is number1*number2/(number1+number2). Your code contains fragments for the arbitrary array of numbers but it is somewhat off the point.

Comment: thank you, i see now that the problem is wit the formula @begemotv2718

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you had in mind when you said harmonic mean, but the harmonic mean of two numbers is the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of their reciprocals.

You don't need to write for loops and other complicated code for it. The following code should do.

```
double harmonic_mean(double number1, double number2) {
    double r1 = 1 / number1;    // reciprocals
    double r2 = 1 / number2;

    double hm = 2 / (r1 + r2);  // reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the two
    return hm;
}
```

Comment: and yes, as others have pointed out, you can "simplify" that to `(2 * n1 * n2)/(n1 + n2)`, but things are clearer this way, especially when you are learning.

Comment: Also, as an aside, temporary variables make it easier when viewing code with a debugger. (Though it isn't that much of a deal in *this* case.) A decent compiler can optimise away the locals in non-debug builds, so you kinda get the best of both worlds.